# Can't use unicode character as rune

Tags: go, unicode, rune

It appears that golang doesn't support all unicode characters for its runes

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  standardSuits := []rune{'♠️', '♣️', '♥️', '♦️'}
  fmt.Println(standardSuits)
}
```

Generates the following error:

```
./main.go:6: missing '
./main.go:6: invalid identifier character U+FE0F '️'
./main.go:6: syntax error: unexpected ️, expecting comma or }
./main.go:6: missing '
./main.go:6: invalid identifier character U+FE0F '️'
./main.go:6: missing '
./main.go:6: invalid identifier character U+FE0F '️'
./main.go:6: missing '
./main.go:6: invalid identifier character U+FE0F '️'
./main.go:6: missing '
./main.go:6: too many errors
```

Is there a way to get around this, or should I just live with this limitation and use something else?

Comment: If you use `[]rune{'♠', '♣', '♥', '♦'}` it seems to work. Apparently U+FE0F is "the variation selector" and it may be that you need to separate your glyph into the code points it's composed off.

Comment: weird how there's an associated variation selector, no wonder it bugs out

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me like a parsing issue. You could use the unicode points to produce that runes, which should give the same result as using the chars.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  standardSuits := []rune{'\u2660', '\u2663', '\u2665', '\u2666', '⌘'}
  fmt.Println(standardSuits)
}
```

Generates

```
[9824 9827 9829 9830 8984]
```

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/jTLsbs7DM1

I added the additional 5th rune to check if the result from code point or char gives the same. Looks like it does.

#### Edit:

Not sure what is wrong with your chars (did not view them in a hex editor, have none around), but something is strange about them.

I also got this to run by copy pasting the chars from Wikipedia:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  standardSuits := []rune{'♠', '♣', '♥', '♦'}
  fmt.Println(standardSuits)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/CKR0u2_IIB

Answer (score 2):

The unicode string you use in your source code consist of more than one "character", but a character constant '...' is not allowed to contain strings of length greater than one.  In more detail:

If I copy&paste your source code and print a hexdump, I can see the exact bytes in your source code:

```
>>> hexdump -C x.go
00000000  70 61 63 6b 61 67 65 20  6d 61 69 6e 0a 0a 69 6d  |package main..im|
00000010  70 6f 72 74 20 22 66 6d  74 22 0a 0a 66 75 6e 63  |port "fmt"..func|
00000020  20 6d 61 69 6e 28 29 20  7b 0a 20 20 73 74 61 6e  | main() {.  stan|
00000030  64 61 72 64 53 75 69 74  73 20 3a 3d 20 5b 5d 72  |dardSuits := []r|
00000040  75 6e 65 7b 27 e2 99 a0  ef b8 8f 27 2c 20 27 e2  |une{'......', '.|
00000050  99 a3 ef b8 8f 27 2c 20  27 e2 99 a5 ef b8 8f 27  |.....', '......'|
00000060  2c 20 27 e2 99 a6 ef b8  8f 27 7d 0a 20 20 66 6d  |, '......'}.  fm|
00000070  74 2e 50 72 69 6e 74 6c  6e 28 73 74 61 6e 64 61  |t.Println(standa|
00000080  72 64 53 75 69 74 73 29  0a 7d 0a                 |rdSuits).}.|
```

This shows, for example, that your `'♠️'` is encoded using the hex bytes `e2 99 a0 ef b8 8f`.  In utf-8 encoding this corresponds to the two(!) characters `\u2660 \uFE0F`.  This is not obvious by looking at the code, since `\uFE0F` is no printable character, but Go complains, because you have more than one character in a character constant.  Using `'♠'` or `'\u2660'` instead works as expected.